# Android: java.lang.IllegalStateException when executing Toast.makeText

Tags: android

I'm getting an Exception when I'm executing this code:

```
public void onClick(View view){
(...)
CharSequence text1 = "Please insert a number.";
 int id= view.getId();
(...)
    else if(id== R.id.buttonOK){
                if(editText.getText().toString().matches(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), text1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

The exception is when Toast.makeText is executed. I've already tried as 1st argument:

**getApplicationContext()**

**this**

**MyActivity.this**

**view.getContext()**

and I always get this error. Can you please help me?

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
```

Comment: Use your activity.this in place of "view.getContext()" this.

Comment: @SurenderKumar didn't work, I got the same error

Comment: Are you sure you are mot making mistake somewhere else?

Comment: is toast statement is executing?

Comment: @Blackbelt can you please explain it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the instance of Activity, for example:

```
MainActivity.this
```

In your case:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error is in the code that you had given is then :

```
//make sure that you had declared and defined editext properly
    else if(id== R.id.buttonOK){
                    if(editText.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "String", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

Comment: I've already used Log.d before Toast.makeTest to check if the problem was on the if, but I could see, it enters into the if without problems, the problem is in the Toast.makeText.